# Export multiple sheets in a single PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

Just wondering how I would be able to export a PDF file to contain multiple sheets, but not all in the workbook. I've been only been able to send single sheets as separate PDF attachments. Any insight on this would be great.

```
  var url = ss.getUrl(); //gets url 
  url = url.replace(/edit/,''); 

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + 
  '&size=letter' + 
  '&portrait=false' + 
  '&fitw=true' + 
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +  
  '&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false' + 
  '&fzr=true' +  
  '&gid=GID'

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, { 
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token 
      } 
    }); 
      var blob = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');
```

Answer (score -1):

A guide has been written about this in this [blog post](http://www.andrewroberts.net/2017/03/apps-script-create-pdf-multi-sheet-google-sheet/) by Andrew Roberts, the source code from that post is as follows:

```
function convertSpreadsheetToPdf(email, spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName) {

  var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId ? spreadsheetId : spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetName ? spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId() : null;  
  var pdfName = pdfName ? pdfName : spreadsheet.getName();
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).getParents();
  var folder = parents.hasNext() ? parents.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if optSheetId is provided
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  folder.createFile(blob);

  if (email) {

    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      "Here is a file named " + pdfName, 
      "Please let me know if you have any questions or comments.", 
      mailOptions);
  }

} // convertSpreadsheetToPdf()

function test() {

  var TEST_EMAIL = 'your email address'

  // Create a PDF containing all the tabs in the active spreadsheet, name it
  // after the spreadsheet, and email it
  convertSpreadsheetToPdf(TEST_EMAIL)

  // Create a PDF containing all the tabs in the spreadsheet specified, name it
  // after the spreadsheet, and email it
  convertSpreadsheetToPdf(TEST_EMAIL, '1r9INcnsyvSQmeduJWVYAvznOOYei9jeAjsy0acA3G1k')

  // Create a PDF just containing the tab 'Sheet2' in the active spreadsheet, specify a name, and email it
  convertSpreadsheetToPdf(TEST_EMAIL, null, 'Sheet2', 'PDF 3')
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers OP's question on how to "export a PDF file to contain multiple sheets, but not all"